# Authenticate with Firebase on IOS using a Phone Number

Tags: ios, iphone, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I am working on a Xamarin Forms application and using an iPhone simulator to test the Firebase authentication using phone number. I have checked all project setup needed on to Console and inside the app but I am getting the

```
Method name: DidReceiveRemoteNotification
Information: {
"com.google.firebase.auth" =     {
    warning = "This fake notification should be forwarded to Firebase Auth.";
};
}
```

all the time. I know that because I am using a simulator I will have to go through recaptcha process for this that has also been done (Added Url Scheme for that). Any help or suggestion that can help me to get this problem sorted will be a great help.